# CodeGeneration to class on Build time from Json file

Tags: c#, .net-core, code-generation

I Wonder is it possible to create a process during the build in dotnet core to do the following.

Lets say that i have a json file containing properties:

```
[
      {
          "name": "Jack",
          "age": "12",
          "issue": "some issue"
      },
      {
          "name": "Jhon",
          "age": "132",
          "issue": "some issue - 1"
      }
  ]
```

And a matching class Preson

```
public class Person
{
  public string Name {get;}
  public string Age {get;}
  public string Issue {get;}

  public Person(string age, string age, string issue)
  {
    ...
  } 
}
```

On build Time or using analyzer I would like to create a class like so

```
public static class Persons
{
    public static Person Jhon => return new Person(...);
}
```

Any thought ?

Comment: There are many ways to achive this. T4 (TT Templates) or Compiler Services or a Custom pre/post build step, which includes code generation via Dom or string.... but why? why not during runtime?...

Comment: Well the data objects are some kind of messages Message.HelpMe => HelpMe turns into an id from the json file